# Ubunty 12.04 - File Manager - Searching fully "ALL" files/folders and sub-folders

Tags: nautilus

I am very frustrated with the default file manager in Ubuntu.  I understand that the default file manager system is Nautilus.  When I want to search the entire file system for any particular word, string, whatever, the resulting search does not list everything that matches my search request.

1. How can I make Nautilus perform a full and complete search of all
   files/folders and sub-folders on my computer?
2. If Nautilus will not do this, what, if any, alternative file manager will work?

I am use to the Windows Explorer file manager and would like to have a similar file manager for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus should do the needs. But if you like to try you could try gnome-search-tool

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool
```

Note that this is just an application and not a new file manager, but anyway if you really like to try other file managers [here](http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/06/20-file-managers-for-ubuntu/) is a link for 20 file manager that could be installed in Ubuntu. Enjoy